Django + React on GPC Cloud Run, post request comes back with a 403 error
I'm attempting to submit a post request for a payment with Stripe. Despite trying many solutions on stackoverflow / reccomendations from CGPT my axios post request is still getting 403 blocked.
I'm using a react frontend and a Django backend.
I have a view get_csrf view looks like this.
def get_csrf(request):     return JsonResponse({"csrf_token": get_token(request)})
My react frontend has the following:
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const csrf = await axios.get("https://##########################.run.app/api/get-csrf");

const csrfToken = csrf.data['csrf_token']; 
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = csrfToken;
Cookies.set('csrftoken', csrfToken);

document.cookie shows there is a csrfcookie set.
The request shows that X-CSRFToken and withCredentials are set.
When submitting the from axios comes back with a 403 response.
GCP logs report: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api/create-payment-intent/
My django settings contain the following:
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
"https://owenmitchell.github.io", 
'http://localhost:3000',
"http://127.0.0.1:3000"]
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'owenmitchell.github.io'

The reactfrontend is setup as a github pages with the above domain name.
My CORS settings are:
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + ['X-CSRFToken',]
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
"http://localhost:3000",  # Frontend URL
"https://owenmitchell.github.io",
"http://127.0.0.1:3000",
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
"GET",
"POST",
"PUT",
"PATCH",
"DELETE",
"OPTIONS",
]

I have django-cors-headers installed, 'corsheaders' is in my installed apps, and the cors middleware is in my middleware at the top.
The post works when I add the csrf_exempt decorator to the view, but as the post request is handling payments bypassing the security seems like a bad idea to me.
Thanks in advance for any help you can offer me.

Have you allowed request-header name X-CSRFToken in your CORS configuration? It looks like you haven't.

Ok, I've added with CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS in my Django Settings. No luck.

Shouldn't axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = csrfToken; appear before the call to axios.get?

I don't believe so, the GET request is working fine and I'm using it to retrieve the token for the POST request I'm making afterwards. That line is to set the header for the POST, and I'm setting the value I've retrieved from the GET.

In what order are you stacking the various middleware? Is the CORS middleware listed first in MIDDLEWARE?

Yes, CORS headers middleware is the first listed.
